Django asynchronous channels blocking websocket
I have an issue with my django channels which I couldn't resolve. Basically, I have a turn-based combat system where messages are received from the client, to signal e.g. the enemy's turn. This happens via a consumer:
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        data = json.loads(text_data)
        message_type = data.get('type')
        if message_type == 'enemy_combat_turn':
            await self.handle_end_of_turn(data)
    
    async def handle_end_of_turn(self, data):
        npc_name = data.get('npc_name')
        debuff = data.get('debuff')
        combat_message = data.get('combat_message')
    
        print(f"Handling end of combat turn for player. Initiating enemy turn next.")
        # Check for active traps first
        response = await trigger_trap(game_id=self.game_id, 
         npc_name=npc_name)
        # Then, trigger enemy combat action
        response = await sync_to_async(enemy_combat_action) 
        (self.game_id, npc_name, debuff, combat_message)
    
    async def send_unified_message(self, event):
        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps(event))
        print(f"Sending message for event {event}")

The consumer awaits several asynchronous functions, e.g. the result of handle_end_of_turn, which is composed of two other asynchronous functions, trigger_trap and enemy_combat_action.
Now, in trigger_trap and in enemy_combat_action, we dispatch messages back to the client e.g.:
 # Send trap message
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        f'character_{game_id}',
        {
            'type': 'send_unified_message',
            'message_type': 'new_assistant_messages',
            'messages': trap_message,
        }
    )

Since the functions are defined asynchronously the expectation is that the messages are sent immediately but instead they seem to be queued up and sent all at the same time once all function call results have been awaited and returned to the main event loop, which seems to be the consumer itself. My hypothesis is that this happens because send_unified_message is blocked from execution since we're still awaiting the results from the other async functions.
What could I do to get around this? I've been trying to get it to work for the last 4 hours but I don't have any more ideas..
